# Update nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to update the value of the specific array element?

```
let data = [
 {title: 'food', category: 'food', value: 10},
 {title: 'good', category: 'hood', value: 40},
 {title: 'sood', category: 'lending', value: 20},
]
```

Comment: you can use index or you will need any unique object identifier

Comment: Share the detail of your question. Share your progress and at least the output you want.

Comment: This is just too basic question, millions of topics about it - Use the search bar or Google

Comment: there does not seem to be any nested object in this example - its an array of objects and the value of each  can be updated by using the index within the array as per yez's answer

Answer (score 0):

- You can simply do this:
  `data[1].value = "aValue"`
- To update all items with title "food":
  `data.filter(e => e.title === "food").forEach(e =>  e.value = "aValue" )`
- To update all items with category "hood":
  `data.filter(e => i.category === "hood").forEach(e =>  e.value = "aValue" )`

Answer (score 0):

Your question was too short to understand but you can try this to update any object by finding it and replacing it by using this function.

```js
  let data = [
     {title: 'food', category: 'food', value: 10},
     {title: 'good', category: 'hood', value: 40},
     {title: 'sood', category: 'lending', value: 20},
  ];

/**
* By this function you can update any array of objects and return the * updated array.
*
* @param    array    data         The data array to update.
* @param    string   findKey      The key to select the object to update.
* @param    string   findValue    The value which has to match for object selection.
* @param    string   replaceKey   Which key to update.
* @param    string   replaceValue replaceKey updated by which value.
*
* @return   array    The updated array.
*/
function update(data, findKey, findValue, replaceKey, replaceValue) {
  return data.map(value => {
    
    if (value[findKey] === findValue) {
      value[replaceKey] = replaceValue;
    }
    
    return value;
  });
}

// Here I update the data array by finding the object which has the 'title' value is 'food' and replace the 'value' field by 50
const updatedData = update(data, 'title', 'food', 'value', 50);

console.log(updatedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :

```
 arr.map((obj) => {

  if(obj.value === 'Old value'){
     obj.value = 'New value'; 
  }

  return obj;

 })
```